# Change layout of views page based on taxonomy term field

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, hooks, theming

I have a taxonomy term page being displayed via a Views 'page' display. I need to change a value in the header of the **site** (above the level of the view) based on the value of one of the fields in the taxonomy term.

The problem is that I can't find the right hook for this. If I hook into `hook_preprocess_views_view`, it's too late. The wrapper that includes the site header has already fired. If I try to run `hook_preprocess_page`, there isn't yet any information in the `$variables` arg to give me the taxonomy ID so I can look up the field value. Unless there is are variables available to the hook in addition those that are passed into function as args, I don't see how I can get the requisite information. Are there other variables I could use that are undocumented or global variables available that just aren't passed to the function/hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is in the `hook_preprocess_page` use the following code :

```
$arg = arg();
if (count($arg) == 3 && $arg[0] == 'taxonomy' && $arg[1] == 'term' && is_numeric($arg[2])) {
  $term = taxonomy_term_load($arg[2]);
  if ($term->vid == $my_vocab_id) {
    # code...
  }
}
```

Then change the value of the header as you want in the `# code...` part.

Basically you check if the URL is a taxonomy term page and then  you can check that the term vid correspond to its proper vocabulary id.

Hope that will help you.

Comment: I see. That function is helpful. That's exactly what I needed.